# adjust css in dompdf

Tags: css, dompdf

I need to accommodate the CSS of dompdf. I have the following in a system and when exporting it, I can't get something similar that fits the pdf sheet........

[image]

[image]

I copied the CSS from the table I have in the system with the CSS Used extension but I am not very good at the CSS issue

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Informe de Reingreso</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .centerTabla {
        text-align: center;
    }

    table{border-collapse:collapse;}
    th{text-align:left;}

    @media print{
        *,*::before,*::after{text-shadow:none!important;box-shadow:none!important;}
        .table th{background-color:#fff!important;}
        .table-bordered th{border:1px solid #ddd!important;}
    }
        *,*::before,*::after{box-sizing:inherit;}
        /*! CSS Used from: Embedded */
        .vertical-text__inner{display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;line-height:1.5;transform:translate(0,100%) rotate(-90deg);transform-origin:0 0;}
        .table{width:100%;max-width:100%;margin-bottom:1rem;background-color:transparent;}
        .table td{padding:0.75rem;vertical-align:top;border-top:1px solid #c2cfd6;}
        .table thead th{vertical-align:bottom;border-bottom:2px solid #c2cfd6;}
        .table-sm th,.table-sm td{padding:0.3rem;}
        .table-bordered{border:1px solid #c2cfd6;}
        .table-bordered th,.table-bordered td{border:1px solid #c2cfd6;}
        .table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd){background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
</style>

<body>

    <section>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group row border">
        <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                <thead >
                    <tr>                                           
                        <th style="height: 150px"><div style="width:5px" class="vertical-text__inner">Nº</div></th>

                        <th style="width:100px">Pensun Academico Aprobado <br> en 2019 -2020 CII</th>

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner" style="width:2px">Nivel</div></th> 

                        <th style="width:80px">Periodo Lectivo</th>   

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner" style="width:1px">Calificación</div></th> 

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner" style="width:2px">Estado</div></th>  

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner" style="width:5px">N° vez tomada</div></th>  

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner">% Equiparacion</div></th>  

                        <th style="width:100px">Pensun Academico Aprobado <br> en 2019 -2020 CII</th>

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner" style="width:2px">Nivel</div></th>   

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner" style="width:15px">Validacion de <br> conocimientos</div></th>   

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner">Calificacion valid. <br>de conocimientos</div></th>  

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner" style="width:2px">Estado</div></th>  

                        <th><div class="vertical-text__inner">N° vez tomada</div></th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($analisisReingreso as $materias)
                    <tr>
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->nVecesTomada}}</td>  <!---contador de materias-->
                    <td>{{$materias->nVecesTomada}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->nivel}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->periodoLectivo}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->calificacion}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->estado}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->nVecesTomada}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->equiparacion}}</td> 
                    <td>{{$materias->asignaturas}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->nivel}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->validacionConocimientos}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->califValidConocimientos}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->estado}}</td> 
                    <td class="centerTabla">{{$materias->nVecesTomada}}</td> 
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <br>
    <br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing I can see is that two of your columns are missing a specified width (% Equiparacion and Calificacion valid. de conocimientos), you might want to try that.

Comment: if I have been testing and changing it but it does not give you the width that I specify

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PDF render tool is using horizontal text instead of vertical text width to determine parent's box width.
This is most likely due to dompdf using an earlier css processor while you are using a recent css rule :

`transform:translate(0,100%) rotate(-90deg);`

Try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode
instead

Comment: leave the class as follows with the example but
  `.vertical-text__inner` only with `writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-orientation: mixed; `and now the entire header is set at the time but the text is horizontal

Answer (score 0):

It is a not so optimal solution but it helps a lot with the presentation.

[image]

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">No</td>
            <td rowspan="2">UF</td>
            <td colspan="8">Sentido</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">PR</td>
            <td colspan="3">Carril</td>
            <td>Indicador Asociado</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wi20px">
                <div class="R90">B</div>
                <div class="R90">G</div>
            </td>
            <td class="wi20px">
            <div class="R90">G</div>
            <div class="R90">B</div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<style>
    .R90 {
        width: 7px;
        height: 7px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    .wi20px {
        width: 10px;
    }
</style>
```